# Read appconfig from project reference

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

On my main project("Demo") I'm added a project reference to some project ("Common").
In "Common" project I'm have app.config file which contain:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="test" value="123"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and a class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
    }
}
```

On my main program ("demo") I'm add this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        Console.WriteLine(c.Get());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Since the app.config running on model of top layer configuration, it's not working.

I'm remember that in the past I'm added to demo project a app.config file with configsection node. But I'm have a problems to do this now - forgot how to do.

Can someone tell me how demo's app.config should looks like?

Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm confused by what you demand. You only want to read the key "test" from the app.settings which is in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

App.Config and Web.Config are always being read from the man executable projects. i.e. you need to add/merge the Common\app.config to your main\app.config